# Please verify my induction proof.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

I would like to show that the following statement is true by the principle of mathematical induction (I must only use induction, not other theorems to justify my answer)

> If $n$ is odd natural number, then $n^3-n$ is divisible by 24.

My proof:

> **Base Case**: For $n=1, n^3-n = 1-1 = 0$ which is divisible by $24$.
>
> **Induction hypothesis**: Assume that that statement is true for $n=2k-1, k∈N$. This means that $(2k-1)^3 - (2k-1)$ is divisible by 24 and hence $(2k-1)^3 - (2k-1) = 24p, p∈N$.
>
> > $(2k-1) [(2k-1)^2-1] = 24p$
> >
> > $(2k-1)[(2k-1-1)(2k-1+1)] = 24p$
> >
> > $(2k-1)[(2k-2)(2k)] = 24p$
> >
> > $8k^3-12k^2+4k=24p$
>
> **Inductive step**: Show that the statement is true for $n=2k+1, k∈N$.
>
> > $n^3-n = (2k+1)^3-(2k+1)$
> >
> > $   = (2k+1)[(2k+1)^2-1]$
> >
> > $=(2k+1)[(2k+1-1)(2k+1+1)]$
> >
> > $=(2k+1)[(2k)(2k+2)]$
> >
> > $=8k^3+12k^2+4k$
> >
> > $=(8k^3-12k^2+4k)+24k^2$
> >
> > $=24p+24k^2$ (Induction hypothesis)
> >
> > $=24(p+k^2)$
> >
> > Both expressions are divisible by $24$, hence the expression is divisible by 24.
>
> We have shown that the statement is true for $n=2k+1$. Therefore, by induction, statement is true for all odd natural numbers n.

**Please give me your suggestions. Thanks!**

Comment: Seems fine to me

Comment: Your proof is right but there is a little mistake. It should be $(2k-1)(2k-2)(2k)=24p $.

Comment: There is a tiny thing in your proof: $(2k-1)^2-1=4k^2-4k=4k(k-1)\neq (2k-1)2k$

Comment: @Ruzayqat where?

Comment: okay, corrected @Charter

Comment: okay, corrected  @Ruzayqat

Comment: Looks correct to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the right idea. Essentially you have verified the following equation

$$ \color{}{(2k+1)^3 -(2k+1)}\, =\ \color{#0a0}{(2k-1)^3 - (2k-1)}\, +\, 24k^2$$

Therefore $\ 24\mid \color{#0a0}{\rm green}\,\Rightarrow\,24\mid\rm RHS\,\Rightarrow\,24\mid LHS,\,$ which yields the inductive step.

**Remark** $\ $ A slicker way to prove that equality is to note that $\,f(k) = \rm RHS-LHS$ is at most *quadratic* (cubic terms cancel), so to verify that it is zero it suffices to show that it has $3$ roots, e.g. verify $\,0 = f(1) = f(2) = f(3).\,$  But this looks like the base of an inductive proof! Indeed, if you study the calculus of finite differences and/or telescopy you will learn even nicer ways to handle such inductive proofs. You can find some examples in my [posts on telescopy.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+telescopy)

Comment: Nice job, Bill (really)!  I like how you address the OP's question and also enriched it!

Answer (score 1):

Induction is not necessary.

$n^3-n=(n-1)n(n+1)$, so at least one of them is multipe of 3.

In addition, if $n$ is  odd, both $n-1$ and $n+1$ are even. In fact one of then must be multiple of 4, so $(n-1)(n+1)$ is multiple of 8.

Hence, $n^3-n$ is multiple of 24.

Comment: @amWhy, relax, Tito isn't hurting anyone, jeez.  Also, your quote from the question is actually an addition made by Bill after Tito already answered.

Comment: @tilper I'm relaxed.  I didn't know that the sentence I quoted was edited in, after it's post. Tito's observations are fine (note, I did not nor will I downvote this answer).  I just really hope that when a questioner asks whether their procedure/proof/solution is correct, that any answerer address that question first.  The best then go on to *also* include alternative approaches, or how to simplify the OP's approach, etc.